# Error: "dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem"

Tags: apt, dpkg, sudo

I think I used  something  involving `dpkg`  but  I am  not  able  to recall what.
After  that when I  need to    do   some

```
sudo-apt
```

get  or  even sudo-apt get  update  I am facing  the  following   issue:

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 
    sudo dpkg --configure -a
 to correct the problem.
```

Any clue what is  wrong and how   can I  fix  this?

Comment: Then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is it says.

Comment: You should read the output, as it says exactly what you must do.

Comment: Check your `.history` file, where `bash` stores commands you type.

Answer (score 20):

It is called when packages are broken, or the package installation is interrupted.

You should run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or its alternative `apt-get -f install` to solve this problem.

Comment: what does `sudo dpkg --configure -a` actually do? I see this command referenced multiple times but not sure what it actually does

Comment: @red888, In Ubuntu, packages are in a .deb file format, which is a zip file that holds compiled source ported into Ubuntu. By installing a package (`apt install <package name>` or `dpkg -i <package name>`)  it downloads then unpacks into `/` and finally configures the package. If package installation is interrupted by some circumstances in configuration phase then this problem occurs...

Comment: @red888, So `dpkg --configure -a` (Syntax: `dpkg` - package installer, `--configure` - start configuration phase, `-a` - all packages) starts the configuration phase again... Then, `apt-get -f install` resolves unmet dependencies as `apt-get` has an ability to automatically install, where `dpkg` can't...