# dpkg was interrupted - need help to fix

Tags: dpkg

dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Here is some of the processes I tried:

```
robterri@system76-pc:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for robterri: 

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
robterri@system76-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install -f

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
robterri@system76-pc:~$ s aux | grep -i apt
s: command not found
robterri@system76-pc:~$ s aux | grep -i apt
s: command not found
robterri@system76-pc:~$ udo dpkg --configure -a
Command 'udo' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install udo

robterri@system76-pc:~$ sudo apt install udo
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 

robterri@system76-pc:~$ udo dpkg --configure -a
Command 'udo' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install udo

robterri@system76-pc:~$ udo dpkg --configure -a
Command 'udo' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install udo

robterri@system76-pc:~$ ps aux | grep -i apt
root        1062  0.0  0.0 137172 10068 ?        Ssl  19:48   0:00 /usr/sbin/thermald --systemd --dbus-enable --adaptive
robterri   19313  0.0  0.0  17864  2376 pts/0    S+   21:00   0:00 grep --color=auto -i apt

robterri@system76-pc:~$ sudo kill -9 19313
kill: (19313): No such process
robterri@system76-pc:~$
```

Used these websites for guide:
[E: dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a)

[Error: "dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721536/error-dpkg-was-interrupted-you-must-manually-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a-t)

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
y

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Goes  to  a screen that states package configuration      Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer   TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA

I think what locked it up was "sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras      Install Multimedia codecs.    Was trying to do "25 things you must do after installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (right now) on YouTube.

Had killed 3 other processes before I started keeping track. Process 14272, 15502, 19313.

```
robterri@system76-pc:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for robterri: 
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 20726 (apt)
```

Tried to upgrade again goes on & on to 150s never stops.

SOLVED

Archisman & Ubuntu commuity:  Thanks for being patient.

I could not figure out how to activate the "OK" button on the package configuration Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA.  The answer and links at the top help solve the problem.

Apologize for not providing OS and details of computer. Lack of sleep did not help.

Thanks again!

Comment: You've not provided your OS & release details, please do so.  You've also not said if you tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as the message tells you to do, you only show you attempting to run it with *typos* without any correction shown of your *typos*.

Comment: If you install a microsoft fonts file, you **must** answer the EULA before you can continue; the hold will be locked until you answer it using the keys that Microsoft's coding requires you to use, breaking the lock is not advisable; you should answer ACCEPT or REJECT (using keyboard).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari) and [how to fix this : " waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 3321 (apt)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1438501/)

Comment: The terminal history shows a lot of not-checking-the-input, and a lot of not-reading-the-output. This seems mostly self-inflicted.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot your computer. It will remove the lock file.

Then run the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (you were previously missing the "s" in `sudo`, which is why the computer said that "udo" not found).

> Goes to a screen that states package configuration Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA

You will have to accept the EULA using your keyboard in order to install this software.